# cppcheck complains Buffer is accessed out of bounds. Why and how do I fix?

Tags: c, cppcheck

Code below to reproduce.  Is cppcheck correct to report an out of bounds error in this case?  Error is reported on line with the memcpy.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t serial_number;
    uint8_t software_version[15];
} STATIC_HARDWARE_DATA;

typedef struct {
    uint16_t              result_code;  
    uint8_t               startup_type; 
    STATIC_HARDWARE_DATA  payment_data; 
} MSG_DETAILS;

int main() {

    MSG_DETAILS msg = {0};
    msg.result_code = 0;
    msg.startup_type = 2;
    msg.payment_data.serial_number = 0xAAAA;
    // on line below cppcheck says: Buffer is accessed out of bounds
    memcpy(msg.payment_data.software_version, "1.01A", 15);

    printf("%s", msg.payment_data.software_version);  // prints correct 1.01A

    /* in memory msg.payment_data.software_version is:
      '1', '.', '0', '1', 'A', '\0', '\0', '\0', '_', '\0', '_', 'n', '\0', 'a'

      The characters on end of array are unexpected?
    */

}
```

Comment: Use the size of `1.01A` instead of `15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string literal `"1.01A"` give you a pointer to an array of six characters, you try to read 15 characters from it. Since you read data out of bounds you have *undefined behavior*, as that contents is *indeterminate*.

Comment: Of course, didn't think of the source.  That explains the strange characters in array.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t serial_number;
    uint8_t software_version[15];
} STATIC_HARDWARE_DATA;

typedef struct {
    uint16_t              result_code;  
    uint8_t               startup_type; 
    STATIC_HARDWARE_DATA  payment_data; 
} MSG_DETAILS;

int main() {

    MSG_DETAILS msg = {0};
    msg.result_code = 0;
    msg.startup_type = 2;
    msg.payment_data.serial_number = 0xAAAA;
    // on line below cppcheck says: Buffer is accessed out of bounds
    memcpy(msg.payment_data.software_version, "1.01A", 6);//<-- size should be 6 including \0.

    printf("%s", msg.payment_data.software_version);  // prints correct 1.01A

    /* in memory msg.payment_data.software_version is:
      '1', '.', '0', '1', 'A', '\0', '\0', '\0', '_', '\0', '_', 'n', '\0', 'a'

      The characters on end of array are unexpected?
    */

}

o/p:
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ gcc gg.c 
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 
1.01A
```